# Symfony2 - How to import parameters using Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\ClosureLoader?

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, dependency-injection, closures

I found the following undocumented feature in the documentation chapter **[Miscellaneous Configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html#miscellaneous-configuration)**:

> A resource file can be one of many types. PHP, XML, YAML, INI, and
>   **closure resources** are all **supported by** the **imports** directive.

The class in charge of loading these resources seems to be:

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\ClosureLoader ( **[APIdoc](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/ClosureLoader.html)** , **[Code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/ClosureLoader.php)** )

In my understanding according to the documentation it should be possible to import services and/or parameters using a **PHP closure** inside a configuration file.

**non-working example:**

```
# app/config/config.yml
imports:
     # closure? something like eval( <multiline-string> ) ?
    - { resource: >  
                    function($containerBuilder) { 
                        return array( 
                            'parameters' => array(
                                'upload_tmp_dir' => ini_get('upload_tmp_dir')
                            )
                         );
                    } 
    }
```

I can't find an example showing how to use this loader in a PHP,XML,YAML configuration file with the **imports** directive.

- **Is there any example available using `imports`?**
- Is the `ClosureLoader` compatible with the `YAML` format?

There is an example available that shows how to use the `Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\ClosureLoader` to load a route collection ( **[Routes as Closures](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html#routes-as-closures)**).

But it does not show how to use the closure with the `imports` directive as the documentation states.

---

The idea behind my question is that it *might* be possible to access PHP's configuration values or some class constants in `config.yml` **without** creating an extension/compiler-pass or importing a file in a different configuration format. ( i.e. accessing constants is **[not possible](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html#component-di-parameters-constants)** in YAML format ).

This would open up some great possibilities ...

... like adding a closure that imports a parameter for the `upload_tmp_dir` path in `php.ini` that can instantly be used in [LiipMonitorBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipMonitorBundle)'s `liip_monitor.checks.writable_directory` array afterwards.

Comment: There was a feature in the Yaml component that evaluated PHP code, [but was soon removed](https://github.com/symfony/Yaml/commit/3686cbcda215d25315cb02d9be6cb55ff26e310e). But your asking could still be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to use that loader in `AppKernel`:

```
class AppKernel extends \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel
{
    // ...

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir() . '/config/config_' . $this->getEnvironment() . '.yml');

        // Load config from the closure
        $loader->load(function () {
           // ..
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that this is not taken into account when recomputing the cache (i.e. if you change your closure, the cache will not change).

Answer (score -1):

to use an ini file you can juste call the file as ressource:

```
- { resource: parameters.ini }
```

theres 4 type of closure with the symfony dependcyInjection Component (Symfony 2.3). there are IniFileLoader, PhpFileLoader, XmlFileLoader and YamlFileLoader.

To use a personal closure you should create you personal closure that extends from 
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\FileLoader

This a good exemple : http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2013/01/30/custom-symfony2-config-loader/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions :) Sadly i do already know how to create a custom loader and of course how to import resources in INI, PHP, XML and YAML format. The documentation states that it is possible to use a closure **inside the imports directive of a configuration file**. My question is only targeting this one specific edge case ... not how to importing  services or parameters generally.